# Unable to deploy in ec2 Ubuntu MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to deploy my MERN stack on an ec2 Ubuntu instance. Everything worked until I installed my project dependencies. My project worked fine in my local but for some reason, I can't fix the dependency issue in the instance (prod):

```
sudo yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to load plugin 'flowtype' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-expressions'
Require stack:
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/eslint-plugin-flowtype/dist/rules/noUnusedExpressions.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/eslint-plugin-flowtype/dist/index.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/config-array-factory.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/index.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/index.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/linter.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /var/www/ubunturadiumlaw/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried to install the dependency individually, with npm, with yarn, and apt-get nothing worked.

Here's my package.json file:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
                "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
                "@popperjs/core": "^2.5.3",
                "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
                "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
                "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
                "algoliasearch": "^4.5.1",
                "algoliasearch-helper": "^3.2.2",
                "axios": "^0.19.2",
                "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
                "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
                "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
                "brew": "0.0.8",
                "compression": "^1.7.4",
                "cors": "^2.8.5",
                "crypto": "^1.0.1",
                "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
                "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
                "express": "^4.17.1",
                "file-system": "^2.2.2",
                "flowtype": "^2.0.0",
                "git": "^0.1.5",
                "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
                "helmet": "^4.1.1",
                "https-localhost": "^4.6.3",
                "instantsearch.css": "^7.4.5",
                "jquery": "^3.5.1",
                "method-override": "^3.0.0",
                "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
                "mongoose": "^5.9.20",
                "multer": "^1.4.2",
                "multer-gridfs-storage": "^4.2.0",
                "node-json-db": "^1.1.0",
                "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
                "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
                "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
                "react": "^17.0.1",
                "react-autosuggest": "^10.0.2",
                "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
                "react-create-app": "^2.0.6",
                "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
                "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.7.0",
                "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
                "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
                "react-tappable": "^1.0.4",
                "react-toastify": "^6.0.4",
                "rfs": "^9.0.3",
                "serve": "^11.3.2",
                "typescript": "^4.0.5",
                "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
                "yarn": "^1.22.10"
        },
        "scripts": {
                "start": "react-scripts start",
                "build": "react-scripts build",
                "test": "react-scripts test",
                "eject": "react-scripts eject"
        }, "eslintConfig": {
                "extends": [
                        "react-app"
                ]
        },
        "browserslist": {
                "production": [
                        ">0.2%",
                        "not dead",
                        "not op_mini all"
                ],
                "development": [
                        "last 1 chrome version",
                        "last 1 firefox version",
                        "last 1 safari version"
                ]
        }
}
```

What is wrong?

Ec2 Ubuntu 20.04
Using Node.js as Server
React
Mongo

Comment: hope this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774157/error-cannot-find-module-eslint-config-flowtype

Comment: Thanks! I was able to produce a build. Much appreciated.