# Failed to load plugin 'flowtype' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint/use-at-your'

Tags: reactjs, eslint, webstorm, create-react-app, flowtype

I start my project at command -> **Create-react-app** 
Yesterday, when I opened my project in WebStorm, 
I saw the following

I tried to change eslint config, but it's doesn't works. I don't know how it fix
*My error in WebStorm:* \

```
ESLint: Error: Failed to load plugin 'flowtype' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint/use-at-your-own-risk'
```

*package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "loft-taxi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.4",
    "flowtype": "^2.0.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.6.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "reseter.css": "^2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.45.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "commit": "cz"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
```

}

.eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype"
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you try installing `eslint-plugin-flowtype`?

Comment: can also be a problem with plugin peer dependencies

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397587/failed-to-load-plugin-flowtype-declared-in-package-json-eslint-config-react. Link of issue to fix can be found here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11856